# How many distinct graph exist with n nodes?

Tags: math, graph, graph-theory

How many distinct graph can I have with n nodes (No label on Nodes, nor weight on Edges)? Is there a formula?
For example for a graph with 3 nodes I can just have a linear shape and a Triangular.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://math.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: Is there a real world problem you are trying to solve by writing some code?

Comment: Also that strongly depends on what you define as "distinct". Is `A-B-C` equal to `A-C-B` or not? But probably this problem is better fitted on https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @derpischer Thank, Yes they are equal, I have no label on node nor weights on edges

Comment: @revenspoint you are true I should have asked this in mathexchange

Answer (score 0):

While we do have formulas for the number of non-isomorphic graphs, it appears that these formulas are quite hard to evaluate. The OEIS [lists the numbers of distinct graphs for many numbers of nodes](https://oeis.org/A000088) and includes references to papers that have worked out the details.

The number of distinct graphs grows extremely quickly as a function of the number of nodes. Asymptotically, the number of n-node non-isomorphic graphs is approximately 2<sup>n(n - 1) / 2</sup> / n!. That intuitively makes sense; the numerator here counts the number of graphs on n labeled nodes, and the denominator counts the number of ways you can rearrange the labels on those nodes. Check the OEIS for links to proofs of this result.